# How are the arguments of a function interpreted in groupby.apply in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

In an Introduction to Data Science in Python course on Coursera, the following example is given:

```py
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b]), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity')
```

where `df` is a DataFrame, and the lambda is applied to calculate the sum of two columns.

If I understand correctly, the groupby object (returned by `groupby`) that the `apply` function is called on is a series of tuples consisting of the index that was grouped by and the part of the DataFrame that is specific to that grouping.

What I don't understand is the way that the lambda is used.

There are three arguments specified (`lambda df,a,b`), but only two are explicitly passed (`'Weight (oz.)'` and `'Quantity'`). How does the interpreter know that arguments `a` and `b` are the ones specified as arguments and `df` is used 'as-is'?

I'm thinking this has to do with `df` being in scope but cannot find information to support and detail that thought.

Comment: `df.groupby('Category')` this groupby object itself it the first argument when you use apply.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. Not completely accurate though as it seems

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The apply method itself passes each "group" of the groupby object as the first argument to the function. So it knows to associate 'Weight' and "Quantity" to `a` and `b` based on position. (eg they are the 2nd and 3rd arguments if you count the first "group" argument.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,11,(10,3)), columns = ['num1','num2','num3'])
df['category'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df = df[['category','num1','num2','num3']]
df

  category  num1  num2  num3
0        a     2     5     2
1        a     5     5     2
2        a     7     3     4
3        b    10     9     1
4        b     4     7     6
5        b     0     5     2
6        b     7     7     5
7        c     2     2     1
8        c     4     3     2
9        c     1     4     6

gb = df.groupby('category')
```

implicit argument is each "group" or in this case each category

```
gb.apply(lambda grp: grp.sum())
```

The "grp" is the first argument to the lambda function
notice I don't have to specify anything for it as it is already, automatically taken to be each group of the groupby object

```
         category  num1  num2  num3
category                           
a             aaa    14    13     8
b            bbbb    21    28    14
c             ccc     7     9     9
```

So apply goes through each of these and performs a sum operation

```
print(gb.groups)
{'a': Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'), 'b': Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64'), 'c': Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}

print('1st GROUP:\n', df.loc[gb.groups['a']])
1st GROUP:
  category  num1  num2  num3
0        a     2     5     2
1        a     5     5     2
2        a     7     3     4    


print('SUM of 1st group:\n', df.loc[gb.groups['a']].sum())

SUM of 1st group:
category    aaa
num1         14
num2         13
num3          8
dtype: object
```

Notice how this is the same as the first row of our previous operation

So apply is *implicitly* passing each group to the function argument as the first argument.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

> GroupBy.apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
>
> args, kwargs : tuple and dict
>
> > Optional positional and keyword arguments to pass to func

Additional Args passed in "*args" get passed *after* the implict group argument.

so using your code

```
gb.apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b]), 'num1', 'num2')

category
a     56
b    167
c     20
dtype: int64
```

here 'num1' and 'num2' are being passed as *additional* arguments to each call of the lambda function

So apply goes through each of these and performs your lambda operation

```
# copy and paste your lambda function
fun = lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b])

print(gb.groups)
{'a': Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'), 'b': Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64'), 'c': Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')}

print('1st GROUP:\n', df.loc[gb.groups['a']])

1st GROUP:
   category  num1  num2  num3
0        a     2     5     2
1        a     5     5     2
2        a     7     3     4

print('Output of 1st group for function "fun":\n', 
fun(df.loc[gb.groups['a']], 'num1','num2'))

Output of 1st group for function "fun":
56
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see what's passed to `groupby.apply` is to `print` it.

```py
# sample 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
    'num1': [9, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 8, 0, 4, 10],
    'num2': [5, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 8, 8, 2, 8],
    'num3': [0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 8, 5, 1]})


# pass print to apply
df.groupby('category').apply(print)

# maybe first two rows of each group is enough
df.groupby('category').apply(lambda g: print(g.head(2)))
```

which outputs:

```
  category  num1  num2  num3
0        a     6     1     2
1        a     1    10     9
  category  num1  num2  num3
3        b     0     5     6
4        b     1     1     5
  category  num1  num2  num3
7        c     5     3     0
8        c     4     4     6
```

As you can see, the dataframe is split into smaller dataframes where the `category` values are the same in each group (because it was used as the grouper). This is the **first argument** passed to lambda.

If the lambda passed to `apply` requires more arguments, they can be supplied either by position (arg) or by keyword (kwarg).

```py
# args
df.groupby('category').apply(lambda g,a,b: sum(g[a] * g[b]), 'num1', 'num2')

# kwargs
df.groupby('category').apply(lambda g,a,b: sum(g[a] * g[b]), a='num1', b='num2')
#                                     ^ ^                    ^^        ^^
# category
# a     77
# b    142
# c     88
# dtype: int64
```